# How to convert the given object with objects to an array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following object that contains objects:

```
{
  "USD": { "7d": "32053.72", "30d": "33194.68", "24h": "31370.42" },
  "AUD": { "7d": "43134.11", "30d": "44219.00", "24h": "42701.11" },
  "RUB": { "7d": "2451451.45", "30d": "2465896.74", "24h": "2398589.80" },
  "timestamp": 1626699964,
  "JPY": { "7d": "3537735.55", "30d": "3664620.47", "24h": "3472632.46" },
  "BRL": { "7d": "167555.18", "30d": "169473.27", "24h": "163054.93" },
  "ILS": { "7d": "108658.72", "30d": "111663.67", "24h": "106988.58" },
  "GBP": { "7d": "23257.66", "30d": "23838.55", "24h": "22923.17" },
  "PLN": { "7d": "124869.61", "30d": "127872.57", "24h": "122668.16" },
  "CAD": { "7d": "40425.62", "30d": "41444.76", "24h": "39827.13" },
  "EUR": { "7d": "27187.74", "30d": "27955.81", "24h": "26659.79" }
}
```

I want to convert it to an array of objects like this:

```
[
 {
  currency: "USD",
  7d: "2451451.45",
  30d: "2465896.74",
  24d: "42701.11"
 },

 {
  currency: "AUD",
  7d: "32053.72",
  30d: "33194.68",
  24d: "2398589.80"
 }
]
```

etc, etc. This is my attempt:

```
var data = { "USD": { "7d": "32053.72", "30d": "33194.68", "24h": "31370.42" }, "AUD": { "7d": "43134.11", "30d": "44219.00", "24h": "42701.11" }, "RUB": { "7d": "2451451.45", "30d": "2465896.74", "24h": "2398589.80" }, "timestamp": 1626699964, "JPY": { "7d": "3537735.55", "30d": "3664620.47", "24h": "3472632.46" }, "BRL": { "7d": "167555.18", "30d": "169473.27", "24h": "163054.93" }, "ILS": { "7d": "108658.72", "30d": "111663.67", "24h": "106988.58" }, "GBP": { "7d": "23257.66", "30d": "23838.55", "24h": "22923.17" }, "PLN": { "7d": "124869.61", "30d": "127872.57", "24h": "122668.16" }, "CAD": { "7d": "40425.62", "30d": "41444.76", "24h": "39827.13" }, "EUR": { "7d": "27187.74", "30d": "27955.81", "24h": "26659.79" } }

var convertedToArray = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
    return data[key];
})
```

It works, but for some reason the `USD`, `AUD` etc currency fields get omitted. How can I get the same output but have the `currency` field included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currency field isn't actually handled by the mapping. It's the key portion for your objects, not one of the values. You need to add the currency field manually.

```
var data = { "USD": { "7d": "32053.72", "30d": "33194.68", "24h": "31370.42" }, "AUD": { "7d": "43134.11", "30d": "44219.00", "24h": "42701.11" }, "RUB": { "7d": "2451451.45", "30d": "2465896.74", "24h": "2398589.80" }, "timestamp": 1626699964, "JPY": { "7d": "3537735.55", "30d": "3664620.47", "24h": "3472632.46" }, "BRL": { "7d": "167555.18", "30d": "169473.27", "24h": "163054.93" }, "ILS": { "7d": "108658.72", "30d": "111663.67", "24h": "106988.58" }, "GBP": { "7d": "23257.66", "30d": "23838.55", "24h": "22923.17" }, "PLN": { "7d": "124869.61", "30d": "127872.57", "24h": "122668.16" }, "CAD": { "7d": "40425.62", "30d": "41444.76", "24h": "39827.13" }, "EUR": { "7d": "27187.74", "30d": "27955.81", "24h": "26659.79" } }

var convertedToArray = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
    return {currency: key, ...data[key]};
})
```

The issue here is that you may need a special check for the timestamp. I'm not sure what you'd like to do there.

Answer (score 0):

osagognitive's solution has a few drawbacks, in my opinion:

- it does not filter out the timestamps, creating a weird `{ currency: "timestamp" }` element
- it accesses the global `data` object in `...data[key]` when constructing the records. Replacing `Object.keys()` with `Object.entries()` would avoid this.

Besides, you can very well define functions instead of abstruse lambdas. Obfuscated JavaScript won't run any faster, but you'll spend a lot more time debugging it, not to mention some else trying to make sense of it.

For instance:

```
function ConvertToCurrencyArray (data) {

  function SelectCurrency ([key, record]) { return key.length == 3 }

  function FormatRecord ([key, record]) { return { currency: key, ...record } }

  return Object.entries(data).filter(SelectCurrency).map(FormatRecord);
}
```

If something goes wrong, you can easily add debug traces:

```
function ConvertToCurrencyArray (data) {

  function SelectCurrency ([key, record]) {
    if (key.length != 3) console.log ("filtering out " + key);
    return key.length == 3
  }

  function FormatRecord ([key, record]) {
    if (Object.keys(record).length != 3) // 3 fields expected
      console.log ("unexpected record " + key + ": " + JSON.stringify(record));

    return { currency: key, ...record }
  }

  return Object.entries(data).filter(SelectCurrency).map(FormatRecord);
}
```

Example:

```
ConvertToCurrencyArray( { "USD": { "7d": "32053.72", "30d": "33194.68", "24h": "31370.42" }, "AUD": { "7d": "43134.11", "30d": "44219.00", "24h": "42701.11" }, "RUB": { "7d": "2451451.45", "30d": "2465896.74", "24h": "2398589.80" }, "timestamp": 1626699964, "JPY": { "7d": "3537735.55", "30d": "3664620.47", "24h": "3472632.46" }, "BRL": { "7d": "167555.18", "30d": "169473.27", "24h": "163054.93" }, "ILS": { "7d": "108658.72", "30d": "111663.67", "24h": "106988.58" }, "GBP": { "7d": "23257.66", "30d": "23838.55" }, "PLNZ": { "7d": "124869.61", "30d": "127872.57", "24h": "122668.16" }, "CAD": { "7d": "40425.62", "30d": "41444.76", "24h": "39827.13" }, "EUR": { "7d": "27187.74", "30d": "27955.81", "24h": "26659.79" } })
```

Output:

```
filtering out timestamp
filtering out PLNZ
unexpected record GBP: {"7d":"23257.66","30d":"23838.55"}
```

Now if you're absolutely sure that

- your input data are 100% reliable and you can read them without any sanity check
- you won't ever need to rethink your output format
- you won't touch this code ever again

you can use this instead:

```
var arrayOfCurrencies = 
  Object.entries(data)
        .filter(([key, record]) => key.length == 3)
        .map   (([key, record]) => ({ currency: key, ...record }))
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you try like below

```
const json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
```